# Is there a way to save Docker container logs automatically?

Tags: docker

The application that I run in a container sends its logs to stdout and this can't be reconfigured. I need these logs to be written to a file to keep them. Is there a way to automatically redirect logs from stdout of a container to a file as soon as the container starts?
(I know about "docker logs" command, but it has to be controlled manually and it is no good if a container stops before logs are saved this way.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it a problem if the container stops? Until the container is deleted, you can still get the logs.

Comment: Configure your favourite log driver: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `entrypoint` with `stdout` and `stderr` redirection to a volume mount.

```
command > /volumemount/out 2>&1
```

Now all the docker logs which used to come to `stdout` of the container will come to the host shared volume. https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file/625230